# Contours of a clandestine nature

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus, geography

What does each of the answers describe? The answer is two words (11 + 4 letters).

> #1
>   [image: rebus 1]
>
> #2
>   [image: rebus 2]
>
> #3
>   [image: rebus 3]
>
> #4
>   [image: rebus 4]

---

<sub>Image credits:
1.2 Slashme, CC BY-SA 4.0;
2.1 AngMoKio, CC BY-SA 2.5;
2.3 Salimfadhley, CC BY-SA 3.0;
4.1 Sodacan, CC BY-SA 3.0</sub>

<sub>This puzzle is part of *[Recycling old answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81150)*.</sub>

Comment: That is a lot of questions, jafe! $(+1)$

Comment: @user477343 Trying to get them all out before they ban me as a spammer!

Comment: will there be a meta puzzle for these puzzles? o.o

Comment: If they ban you from Puzzling, jafe, it will be an extreme disservice ;)

Comment: @athin See edit!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each answer describes

> an UNDERGROUND LINE on the London tube. Also clued by the title: clandestine = underground and contour = line

1

> D, in (pin -p), Washington DC : the D in Washington DC stands for DISTRICT

2

> New York, Opera, Venue (avenue - A) : the METROPOLITAN is an opera house in NYC

3

> National (nationals -s), Captial, Seychelles : the capital city of Seychelles is VICTORIA

4

> Belgium, Battle, Site : WATERLOO is a famous battle site in Belgium

Credit to the other two answers [1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81154/20466) and [2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81152/20466) which both gave partial answers that helped me along the way.

Comment: Great answer! Now the question is what the precise two words are: because I could see other variations such as r13("haqretebhaq fgngvbaf") or r13("ghor fgngvbaf") as well...

Comment: nice answer! +1

Comment: @El-Guest we are told 11+4 letters so I'm reasonably confident of the version I've chosen. Only slight doubt is that 4 is only a partial name for an r13(haqretebhaq yvar). 1 and 2 are definitely r13(yvarf naq abg fgngvbaf) though.

Comment: Also, thinking about the question title, I am sure I have the right wording.

Comment: You both might consider using this format for [rot13 comments](//puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6577):  rot13(Uv zbz!). One of our regulars [wrote a userscript](//stackapps.com/q/7927) to decode rot13 text on hover, and using that format for such text is a welcome convenience for those of us with that userscript.

Answer (score 7):

#2

> Manhattan opera venue (avenue - a)?

#3

> National (Nationals - s) capital (A is the only capital letter) ... flag? >_>

#4 may simply point to

> a (1) Belgian (2) battle (3) site, such as Ypres, Waterloo, etc. No clue yet as to how the other lines could fit in.

Answer (score 5):

Partial:

1:

> DINWA: D (D note in bass clef) + IN (pin-'p') + WA (Washington DC Map)

2:

> NY (New York) + ? (Opera browser logo)+ ?

3:

> WH (Washignton Nationals: WSH - 's') + ? + SYC/SC (Seychelles national flag)

4:

> BE/BEL (Belgium coat of arms) + ? (The Battle of Arica/ Latin American Wars of Independence) + SITE (campsite/gravesite/website)

Comment: 3, picture one is the logo of the Washington Nationals